# What would happen after my Evernote account reaches note/ notebook/ tag limit?

Tags: evernote

[A single Evernote account can't accommodate unlimited no. of notes, notebooks, tags.](https://support.evernote.com/ics/support/KBAnswer.asp?questionID=614) So, I'm worried about it. What happens after reaching the limit? Do they say to create new account or close account? Is there any workaround or prioritized action for premium customer? Has anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: There are also upload limits to consider. Or are you only creating 1000's of small notes (of which there is a max of 100,000)? If you are uploading/syncing large multi-MB notes then you are likely to reach the upload limits long before the number of notes limit.

Comment: @w3d I don't care about upload limit as I am a premium user. Currently, 1GB/month is enough for me. And, I can always purchase more if needed. But, in case of the problem of the question, Evernote hasn't mentioned whether I can purchase more nodes or not.

Answer (score 1):

The limits are considerably generous and practically unreachable. I do not think that any one human being in a single lifetime will be actually able to exhaust these limits - not unless you are deliberately taking it as a sport

To answer your question, when the limit is crossed, you will not be able to create any more notes or notebooks or tags. Whether they ask you to delete a few things or create a new account is only a matter of their user interface and are only suggestions ad do not reflect on anything of technical nature. This is the same as reaching the total space limit in email providers, online storage and stuff like that.

Comment: I already have over 100 notebooks. I am worried that I can reach the limit of no. of notebooks.

Comment: Have a look at your notebooks, are they properly organised? Don't you have a few notebooks that can be combined to a single notebook. Don't you have a few other notebooks that you no longer need. Don't you have a few notebooks that you never needed at all - information that can be in some other service and form and does notrequires evernote at all. You should take this question to personal productivity.stack exchange.com.